# R working with date variables as conditions in if statement

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with columns "month" and "fiscal". "month" has date variables of 1-12, and fiscal indicates fiscal year of either 2021 or 2022

Each column has date variables formatted using as.POSIXct

I am trying to change the "fiscal" column, so that if the month is November or December, we would need to add 1 to the fiscal year

For example:

```
month           fiscal
3               2021
11              2021
12              2021
```

I want this:

```
month           fiscal
3               2021
11              2022
12              2022
```

I tried:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(fiscal, ~ ifelse(month >= 11, fiscal + 1, fiscal)))
```

But got:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(fiscal, ~ifelse(month >= 11, fiscal + 1, fiscal))`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `fiscal`.
Caused by error in `fiscal + 1`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Does anyone know how I should proceed?

Comment: you can just do `mutate(fiscal = ifelse(month >= 11, fiscal + 1, fiscal))`

Comment: Yep, the `across` is not needed at all.

Comment: @micahkimel thanks! it now says Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `fiscal = ifelse(month >= 11, fiscal + 1, fiscal)`.
Caused by error in `fiscal + 1`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: That error likely means that your `month` is string, not numeric (see `"a" + 1`). You need to decide what your data should be and fix it if needed; if it should be strings, then adding one to it will take deliberate indirection.

Comment: @r2evans the values are in date format using as.POSIXct. I don't think they are strings? Is there no way i can manipulate values in date format?

Comment: Your example didn't have any date-time values.

Comment: @IRTFM they were obtained from a column of date time values using this:                     
df$fiscal<- df$Business.Date %>%
  as.POSIXct( format= "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") %>% 
  format(format = "%Y") `                                                                                                   Would that still be a date-time value?

Comment: Nope. The `format` function returns character values. Which is why you cannot add 1 to it. Perhaps using as.numeric to make it "incrementable"?